# Regex group for multiple lines

Tags: regex

Need to write regex such that log divide in group till next **INFO**.

For example:

```
INFO 2015-07-30 06:50:48,208 Request: POST: /api/v1/jobs/
Request Data: {u'job_id': u'15488'}
Resp Status: 200
Resp Data: {'detail': 'ok'}
Resp Time: 0.0139939785004
INFO 2015-07-30 06:50:48,571 Request: POST: /api/v1/jobs/
Request Data: {u'job_id': u'15232 195049139026\r\n'}
Exception Raised: NOTFOUND
Resp Status: 200
Resp Data: {'detail': 'ok'}
Resp Time: 0.0570251941681
```

After regex, group will be:

```
INFO 2015-07-30 06:50:48,208 Request: POST: /api/v1/jobs/
Request Data: {u'job_id': u'15488'}
Resp Status: 200
Resp Data: {'detail': 'ok'}
Resp Time: 0.0139939785004
```

---

```
INFO 2015-07-30 06:50:48,571 Request: POST: /api/v1/jobs/
Request Data: {u'job_id': u'15232 195049139026\r\n'}
Exception Raised: NOTFOUND
Resp Status: 200
Resp Data: {'detail': 'ok'}
Resp Time: 0.0570251941681
```

Comment: Can't you just read the file line by line and detect the status at the beginning of the line?

Comment: I need to do it through regex only.

Comment: It's unclear what your environment is. Programming language? Tool? Text editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/INFO(?:\n(?!INFO)|.)*/g
```

should do it: [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qR5dA0/1).

The RegEx matches `INFO`, followed by this uncaptured group (`(?:…)`): either match a line break (`\n`) that is *not* followed by another `INFO` (`(?!INFO)`), or (`|`) any character (`.`), any number of times (`*`).

You’d think it should be something like “`INFO` followed by anything, repeated”, but unfortunately, it will give the entire string as one giant result, therefore there had to be a negative look-ahead: `(?!INFO)`.

Comment: its working. Thanks :-) 

It will be nice if you can explain it.

Comment: my one almost the same as you so I don't post it separately. 
Just a little bit different.

`^(INFO[^I]+)(?=INFO|$)`

Comment: @zolo This doesn’t seem to work… I just tested this with RegEx101…

Answer (score 2):

`grep` command to match these blocks separately:

```
grep -zoP '(?s)INFO.+?\n(?=(INFO|$))' file

-o              # capture the match
-z              # to treat the input as a set of lines
-P              # Use PCRE regex
(?s)            # DOTALL to make dot match newlines as well
INFO.+?\n       # match INFO and 1 or more any character (non-greedy) till a new line
(?=\n(INFO|$))  # Lookahead to match until next set of character is INFO or end of file
```

**Output:**

```
INFO 2015-07-30 06:50:48,208 Request: POST: /api/v1/jobs/
Request Data: {u'job_id': u'15488'}
Resp Status: 200
Resp Data: {'detail': 'ok'}
Resp Time: 0.0139939785004

INFO 2015-07-30 06:50:48,571 Request: POST: /api/v1/jobs/
Request Data: {u'job_id': u'15232 195049139026\r\n'}
Exception Raised: NOTFOUND
Resp Status: 200
Resp Data: {'detail': 'ok'}
Resp Time: 0.0570251941681

...
```

Comment: Only a little addition, \z may be replaced with $ and would work the same way.

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to change it. \z works perfectly right as well. Also as I never used \z yet and didn't know -z for grep I learnt few new things already. :) So thanks for them!

Comment: @zolo: It works because of `P` flag (which uses Perl regex)