# regex group multiple lines with reverse match

Tags: regex, grep

Need to write regex such that if **Resp Time: {{time}}** is greater than one than print INFO till Resp Time.

Platform: using grep -E, But it will be okay if you just provide regex.

For example:

```
INFO 2015-07-30 06:50:48,208 Request: POST: /api/v1/jobs/
Request Data: {u'job_id': u'15488'}
Resp Status: 200
Resp Data: {'detail': 'ok'}
Resp Time: 1.0139939785004
INFO 2015-07-30 06:50:48,571 Request: POST: /api/v1/jobs/
Request Data: {u'job_id': u'15232 195049139026\r\n'}
Exception Raised: NOTFOUND
Resp Status: 200
Resp Data: {'detail': 'ok'}
Resp Time: 0.0570251941681
INFO 2015-07-30 06:50:48,571 Request: POST: /api/v1/jobs/
Request Data: {u'job_id': u'152195049139026\r\n'}
Exception Raised: NOTFOUND
Resp Status: 200
Resp Data: {'detail': 'ok'}
Resp Time: 1.0570251941681
```

After regex, group will be:

```
INFO 2015-07-30 06:50:48,208 Request: POST: /api/v1/jobs/
Request Data: {u'job_id': u'15488'}
Resp Status: 200
Resp Data: {'detail': 'ok'}
Resp Time: 1.0139939785004
INFO 2015-07-30 06:50:48,571 Request: POST: /api/v1/jobs/
Request Data: {u'job_id': u'152195049139026\r\n'}
Exception Raised: NOTFOUND
Resp Status: 200
Resp Data: {'detail': 'ok'}
Resp Time: 1.0570251941681
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Why did it fail?

Comment: There are some/many case where regexp just isn't for the job alone. Maybe you could make a regexp for it, but will run much much slower than a simple program.

Comment: @erisco , I was trying to replace \n to some KEY till next info (http://stackoverflow.com/a/31730421/2000121) and then grep resp time > 1 and then again replace KEY to \n. But I was thinking if it can be possible with single regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed $'s/^INFO/\\\n&/' file | awk -v RS= 'match($0, "Resp Time: +(.+)", a) && a[1]>=1'

INFO 2015-07-30 06:50:48,208 Request: POST: /api/v1/jobs/
Request Data: {u'job_id': u'15488'}
Resp Status: 200
Resp Data: {'detail': 'ok'}
Resp Time: 1.0139939785004    
INFO 2015-07-30 06:50:48,571 Request: POST: /api/v1/jobs/
Request Data: {u'job_id': u'152195049139026\r\n'}
Exception Raised: NOTFOUND
Resp Status: 200
Resp Data: {'detail': 'ok'}
Resp Time: 1.0570251941681
```

- `sed $'s/^INFO/\\\n&/' file` is just used to insert a newline before `INFO`.
- `awk` command used a null `RS` to break each `INFO` block into a single record.
- `match` is used for matching part after `Resp Time:` text into `a[1]`.
- `a[1]>=1` is the simple condition to check if response time is `>= 1`.

---

**UPDATE:** For non-gnu awk version you can use:

```
awk -F': ' '/^INFO /{a=$0;next} {a = a ORS $0} $1=="Resp Time" && $2>=1{print a}' file.log
INFO 2015-07-30 06:50:48,208 Request: POST: /api/v1/jobs/
Request Data: {u'job_id': u'15488'}
Resp Status: 200
Resp Data: {'detail': 'ok'}
Resp Time: 1.0139939785004
INFO 2015-07-30 06:50:48,571 Request: POST: /api/v1/jobs/
Request Data: {u'job_id': u'152195049139026\r\n'}
Exception Raised: NOTFOUND
Resp Status: 200
Resp Data: {'detail': 'ok'}
Resp Time: 1.0570251941681
```

Comment: getting syntax error. "awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,"

Comment: Trying to run under linux, where match() waiting only 2 parameter inside, not 3.

Comment: I cannot install it on production machine

Comment: Check my **UPDATE** section for BSD awk solution.

Comment: non-gnu one works perfectly, other I couldn't test but I believe it does also.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution with commands /no regexp here/:

```
cat filename |tr '\n' '@'|sed 's/INFO/\n&/g'|grep "Resp Time: 1"|sed 's/@/\n/g'
```

Comment: wow! 5 commands `cat, tr, sed, grep, sed` for a single awk. And not to forget this can break in so many ways.

Comment: You are perfectly right. If someone knows how to make with awk, then with awk it is much better, faster, professional. This isn't that professional, but I didn't tell it is. :)